# Cannot find SenTestingKit when using Kiwi

Tags: iphone, xcode, testing, sentestingkit

Xcode 4.0.2. 
New project, include Tests.
Drag Kiwi folder in.
Cannot find SenTestCase, cannot find #import 
Searched in the framework add list and didn't see it there, either. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had the targets set wrong. SenTesting is only available to the test target.